# Why do my out fields change what map points are displayed on my map?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I have a feature layer within my map control. When I do not list out fields on the feature layer control within the LayerCollection, I see the points, and they appear as expected as I navigate around the map.

BUT, when I add a single outfield that exists, the map points no longer appear! I know the layer can display them, because when I filter the layer for a specific value within the outfield attribute, The point appears.

when it appears though, navigating around the map will change if the point is displayed. for example, if I zoom in, where the point no longer is in the map, and pan to its position, it no longer is there. When I zoom out or in, it appears, but if the extent does not display the point when zooming, it disappears.

What the heck is going on?

Comment: What happens if you assign * to the outfields?  What version are you running? (2.2 has been recently released).

Comment: Hey Kirk, I added the * as an outfield, and still seeing the same weirdness. I am running on version 2.1 of the silverlight api

Comment: Do you see anything strange with Fiddler?

Comment: I'd upgrade to 2.2,  you can have both 2.2 and 2.1 installed and just change you references back to 2.1 if you run into problems.

Comment: You mention "within my map control", implying that the problem occurs within a larger application. Does the problem also occur with a simple sample (eg http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#FeatureLayerSimple). If so, your dataset might be corrupt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found what my problem was. The issue was due to some corrupted data within my SDE. When I looked at the results returned from the API's Query view, It looked like the following:

```
Attributes: 
FeatureName: 
Attributes: 
FeatureName: 
Attributes: 
FeatureName: null
Attributes: 
FeatureName: Nate
Point:
X: -110.823576886
Y: 50.9836569070001
Attributes: 
FeatureName:
Point:
X: -60.5016683889999
Y: 72.3444238000001
Attributes: 
FeatureName:
Point:
X: 4.21404655400005
Y: 55.818870314
Attributes: 
FeatureName:
Point:
X: -10.8027368179999
Y: 75.7814236040001
Attributes: 
FeatureName:
Point:
X: 19.4066767670001
Y: 69.7813095980001
Attributes: 
FeatureName: test
Point:
X: -94.7538058349999
Y: 31.314127516
Attributes: 
FeatureName: test
Point:
X: -101.999665986
Y: 46.38551663
Attributes: 
FeatureName: test
Point:
X: -72.5955695569999
Y: 31.5355270680001
```

As you can see, there were a bunch of leading attributes, that did not have any existing point data. Once I removed this corrupted data from the database, all of the points appeared as expected.

Thank you for the hint to look at the results from the API. As you can see, it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the number of points that will be returned from calls to the REST API when you request additional attribute data.  I don't think there is a limit if you only request geometry and objectID.

See [this discussion thread](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2455&t=291758#909264) for more information.

Comment: this article does not make much sense in the context of my question. The article discusses how the api describes when to send down the data based upon the max limit of points. My map has 5 points drawn by the user, and when there are no outfields specified, the 5 points appear correctly. I add one outfield, and all but one of the points disappear off the map. this is my question.